# BUG - ProteaAudio with Lua does not work

Tags: linux, lua, centos, fedora

Any idea why i cant use or cant build in Lua the ProTeaAudio ?

1) Exist

```
[root@example ~]# yum install lua-devel
Loaded plugins: presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Package lua-devel-5.1.4-4.fc12.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

2) get failed to build the RtAudio

```
[sun@example proteaAudio_src_090204]$ make
g++ -O2 -Wall  -DHAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY -D__LINUX_ALSA__  -Irtaudio -Irtaudio/include -I../lua/src -I../archive/baseCode/include -c rtaudio/RtAudio.cpp -o rtaudio/RtAudio.o
rtaudio/RtAudio.cpp:365: error: no ‘unsigned int RtApi::getStreamSampleRate()’ member function declared in class ‘RtApi’
rtaudio/RtAudio.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool RtApiAlsa::probeDeviceOpen(unsigned int, RtApi::StreamMode, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, RtAudioFormat, unsigned int*, RtAudio::StreamOptions*)’:
rtaudio/RtAudio.cpp:5835: error: ‘RTAUDIO_SCHEDULE_REALTIME’ was not declared in this scope
rtaudio/RtAudio.cpp:5837: error: ‘struct RtAudio::StreamOptions’ has no member named ‘priority’
make: *** [rtaudio/RtAudio.o] Error 1
[sun@example proteaAudio_src_090204]$ 


Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require("proAudioRt");
    stdin:1: module 'proAudioRt' not found:
     no field package.preload['proAudioRt']
     no file './proAudioRt.lua'
     no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/proAudioRt.lua'
     no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/proAudioRt/init.lua'
     no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/proAudioRt.lua'
     no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/proAudioRt/init.lua'
     no file './proAudioRt.so'
     no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/proAudioRt.so'
     no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
    stack traceback:
     [C]: in function 'require'
     stdin:1: in main chunk
     [C]: ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua is trying to tell you that it cannot find an implementation of the module `"proAudioRt"` which it tried to find in a variety of places. The first block of places are various attempts at loading an implementation in Lua, then there are a few tries at various shared object files that might have contained the module. Since none of the places work, [`require`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require) fails.

None worked, because you haven't actually built a .so containing the module.

You need to get all of the compile and link errors to clear up so that you build `proAudioRt.so`. Note that for that to actually contain a Lua module, it must have a C callable entry point named `luaopen_proAudioRt()`, with the signature

```
LUALIB_API int luaopen_proAudioRt(lua_State *L);
```

That function is expected to construct the module's table, supplying it with members containing the functions of the module.  The function [`luaL_register()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_register) is handy for this.

The Lua users wiki has a section on [binding to Lua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BindingCodeToLua) that should be helpful as well.

Comment: No the above didnt worked, even though it compiled successfully, but didnt created any "proAudioRt.so"

Comment: [root@example proteaAudio_src_090204]# ldd ./proAudioRt.so
ldd: ./proAudioRt.so: No such file or directory

Comment: I have no experience with proAudioRt. All I can tell you is what Lua needs to see in order to `require` a module. It is always possible that the library you are building is not already directly compatible with Lua and that you will need to create a wrapper for it.